# C++ Allegro Bitmapping Child Classes

Tags: c++, class, parent-child, allegro

I have two child classes which are calling the same parent function.

One works fine, but the second call of it can't get past the `al_convert_mask_to_alpha` line.

I'm bamboozled once again.

Does anyone know why this may be happening?

The function below is what they both call. With the declarations of both above it.

```
Monster* the_monster = new Monster("chard", 10, 10, "assets/monstertrans.bmp");
Hero* the_hero = new Hero(1, "Player", 20, 20, "assets/hero.bmp");

the_monster->Display();
the_hero->Display();


void Creature::Display(void)
{
    //creating the bitmap
    al_init_image_addon(); //allegro image addon

    //FORGETTING THIS LINE WAS A SILLY IDEA!!!!
    creature_bit = al_load_bitmap(m_filename.c_str()); 

    al_convert_mask_to_alpha(creature_bit, al_map_rgb(255,0,255));

    al_draw_bitmap(creature_bit, m_xpos, m_ypos, 0);

    if (!creature_bit)
    {
        cout << "creature creation failed!" << endl;
        cout << "Any key to exit" << endl;
        _getch();
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (!creature_bit)` --- don't you think it's a bit late to check the bitmap after you have converted and drawn it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not organized very well.

- Initializing the add on should only happen one time at program start
- Loading the bitmap should happen as part of the object's constructor (or immediately after, one time only)
- Drawing the bitmap should happen once per frame (separate from the logic of updating the creature's x/y data)

Those all belong in separate methods.

If `creature_bit` is `null`, then you should read [this article](http://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Loading_Resources_(Troubleshooting)) as it contains everything you need to know about how to load a bitmap properly.